# XAMPP virtual host loading the same as localhost (), but not the document root I have specified

Tags: server, apache2, 22.04, xampp

I am trying to create a virtual host for my XAMPP project. I have created the virtual host and this is working, but it is not loading the DocumentRoot I have specified, only the root directory (the same as browsing to localhost).

Configured in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myproject.develop
```

Uncommented in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Configured virtual host in /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/public/"
    ServerName myproject.develop
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/public/">
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The virtual host does appear to be working, as I can browse to myproject.develop, but this is not loading the public directory to display the web app, it is only displaying the root directory (same as browsing to localhost). Any ideas?¬

Comment: Two questions: (1) is the missing `/` in front of the path in your `Include` a typo? (2) have you restarted Apache since making the configuration changes? XAMPP is an incomplete tool at the best of times. If you plan on working with web servers going forward, you may want to consider using the standard Apache, DB, and PHP packages that ship with Ubuntu. This way you can learn some skills that employers will seek and appreciate 

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @matigo. `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` is the default and it breaks when I add the leading `/`. I have restarted apache service and also changed the virtual host configuration to myproject.test (this is still working but not loading the public directory to display the web app, simply opens the root directory for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

1. in `/etc/hosts`:

   ```
   127.0.0.1   x2cpay.test
   ```
2. in `/opt/lampp/apache2/httpd.conf`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/c2cpay/public"
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     ServerName c2cpay.test
     ServerAlias c2cpay.test
     <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/c2cpay/public">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride all
         Order Deny,Allow
         Allow from all
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Restart apache.